# Custom "At least" attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to create an attribute to validate my model.

In my model I have a list. That list must have a determined number of items that matches a criteria, like "at least 1 active Item" or "at least 1 active item with "John" as its name".

My code is something like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    [AtLeast(1, new Tuple<string, object>("Active", true))]
    public List<Item> ListOfSomething { get; set; }

    [AtLeast(1, new Tuple<string, object>("Active", true), new Tuple<string, object>("Name", "John"))]
    public List<Item> AnotherList { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
}
public class AtLeastAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public int MinLength { get; set; }
    public Tuple<string, object>[] PropertiesAndValues { get; set; }


    public AtLeastAttribute(int minLength,params Tuple<string, object>[] propsNValues)
    {
        MinLength = minLength;
        PropertiesAndValues = propsNValues;
    }
}
```

I was trying to pass a `Tuple<string, object>` to say the Property and the wanted value. But I'm getting this error:

> An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression
>   or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type

Anyone has a way to do this?

Comment: Perhaps instead of tuples, pass in pairs of parameters, or a concatenated string like `"Active,True", "Name,John"`?

Comment: You could store your Tuples in a static dictionary and give the key to the AtLeast attribute.  `[AtLeast(1,"IsActiveTrue")]`, but DavidG's proposal works for data items that easily convert to and from string, which would probably be most of what you would use this for.

Answer (score 0):

Agreeing with the comment by DavidG; the only way to do this is to supply some kind of constant-create expressions basically limiting to primitive types. If you want to implement this then all the constraint values you specify should be convertible from a string.

Then you can think of some syntax like

```
Name=John;Active=True
```

But it's not that simple, you might want to include `;` or `=` in your string values, so you need to figure out some string syntax and escape character:

```
Name='John\\'s Pizza'
```

Or

```
Name='John''s Pizza'
```

Then you need to parse this information; a regex might be able to do it.

If you can do without string values containing the characters you use for splitting, just split the string on `;` then `=` and presto.